# ERROR: Could not find function "dmy" when Deploying App to Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My app works correctly locally on my computer when I use runApp().

The problem is when I want to deploy it it gives me an error that it can't find a function:
ERROR: no se pudo encontrar la función "dmy"

which translates to:
ERROR: Could not find the function "dmy".

I know this function is part of lubridate (which I have locally) and I know I should install it in the server but I can't. I've looked around and I can't find where 
    `library(lubridate)`
should go.

Here is my code (sorry for the bad syntax but Im new in Shiny):

```
#Comienzo la aplicaciÃ³n

#Cargo las librerÃ­as
require(shiny)
require(rsconnect)
require(lubridate)

#Cambio el directorio (solo lo uso si lo voy a correr local)
#setwd("C:/Users/borja.sanz/Desktop/Borja/R/Shiny/Directorio - Proyecciones Productos")


#Cargo los datos
data<-read.csv("./data/Pruebas Shiny.csv")

#Obtengo los niveles de cada factor
Producto.Maestro = levels(data$Producto.Maestro)
Producto = levels(data$Producto)
Pais = levels(data$Pais)

#Cambio las fechas a formato de fecha
data$Fecha = dmy(data$Fecha)

#Extraigo el aÃ±o
data$AÃ±o = as.factor(year(data$Fecha))

#Obtengo los niveles de AÃ±o
AÃ±os = levels(data$AÃ±o)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
#Comienzo la interfaz de usuario
ui <-
  shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Proyecciones de Productos"),
    #Creo los inputs del sidebar
      sidebarPanel(uiOutput("duracion"),
                   uiOutput("pais"),
                   uiOutput("aÃ±o"),
                   uiOutput("producto.maestro"),
                   uiOutput("producto")),
      mainPanel()
  )
)


#Comienzo el archivo de servidor
require(shiny)
require(lubridate)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$duracion = renderUI(sliderInput(inputId = "duracion",
                                         label = "Seleccione la duraciÃ³n de su promociÃ³n:",
                                         value = 45, min = 15, max = 90)
  )

  output$pais = renderUI(selectInput(inputId = "pais",
                                     label = "",
                                     choices = c("Seleccione un paÃ­s",levels(data$Pais)),
                                     selected = "Seleccione un paÃ­s")
  )

  output$aÃ±o = renderUI(selectInput(inputId = "aÃ±o",
                                     label = NULL,
                                     choices = c("Seleccione un aÃ±o",levels(data$AÃ±o)),
                                     selected = "Seleccione un aÃ±o")
  )

  output$producto.maestro = renderUI(
        selectInput(inputId = "producto.maestro",
                        label = NULL,
                        choices = c("Seleccione un producto maestro",levels(data$Producto.Maestro[which(data$Pais == input$pais & data$AÃ±o == input$aÃ±o)])),
                        selected = "Seleccione un producto maestro")
  )

  output$producto = renderUI(
    if(input$pais == "Seleccione un paÃ­s" || input$aÃ±o == "Seleccione un aÃ±o" || input$producto.maestro == "Seleccione un producto maestro"){return()
     }else selectInput(inputId = "producto",
                     label = NULL,
                     choices = c("Seleccione los productos relevantes",levels(factor(data$Producto[which(data$Pais == input$pais & data$Producto.Maestro == input$producto.maestro)]))),
                     selected = levels(factor(data$Producto[which(data$Pais == input$pais & data$Producto.Maestro == input$producto.maestro)])),
                     multiple = TRUE)
  )
}

#Corro la aplicaciÃ³n
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You probably didn't load the lubridate package. I also have some concerns about unquoted names like `AÃ±os`

Comment: @42- I have fixed the weird characters. They happened because of encoding when saving. I know I didn't load the lubridate package but my question is where in my code should it go to get loaded on to the server?

Answer (score 0):

A work-around might be to use

`lubridate::dmy()` instead of loading the lubridate package with `require()` or `library()`. Doing so requires a little more typing, since you would need to replace any instance of `dmy()` with `lubridate::dmy()`.

Comment: that didn't work so I just used as.POSIXct instead of lubridate. However, I'm now getting the same error for ggplot. Any help?

Comment: Is your code in a single file, app.R? I'm new to shiny, too, so I'm trying to see if I can reproduce your error. I'm not sure what you mean by "deploy" the app.

Comment: Have you successfully deployed other apps? If not, you might want to verify that you're successfully deploying apps. You could, for example, try to deploy an app from the RStudio gallery: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/. that way, you'll have an app that is known to work properly, so you can troubleshoot the possibility that there's an error in your deployment procedure.

Comment: Hi.
I solved it by changing input$Año and data$Año to input$ano and data$ano. That was causing an error when parsing.
What I mean by deploying is getting it to shinyapps.io as a website.

Comment: Cool - thanks for the explanation. I'm glad that it worked out!!